# Remove ubuntu and download kali linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I'm trying to remove ubuntu and download kali from an old pc I have. I've downloaded the image and burnt a usb using ubuntu startup disk creator. I've used [this link](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-bare-metal) to get the iso. When I plug in the usb it doesn't do anything. When I enter BIOS by clicking f2, I've put usb boot above ubuntu, now it says `Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*` when I startup. My pc also has windows 8 on it, since the pc is old I want to remove both windows and ubuntu and only want kali installed.

Comment: Download the Kali installer (bare metal installer) from the Kali website. Format your disk to remove Windows and Ubuntu, and then install Kali.

Comment: @John Is there a tutorial for that? how do I format my usb to remove windows and ubuntu?

Comment: Here:   https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/   I have a Kali VM running.

Comment: If you're asking for tutorial for a simple OS installation then definitely you SHOULDN'T be using Kali. This is a very specific distro target to very specific people - definitely not you - and it ISN'T designed for usage as a daily driver desktop Linux. Do yourself a favor and install Ubuntu or Mint or whatever instead.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for your advice, However I can't learn kali without installing it now can I? I'm mostly a programmer using ubuntu on my other laptops, I just have an old pc lying around and want to experiment around using kali as a hobby.

Comment: Yes you surely can without installing it and as a matter of fact that's the preferred way. Live session or a VM as above.

Comment: But actually there's nothing Kali specific to learn about Kali that you can't learn, faster and easier, in any Debian or derivative. The tools that come with it is what you may want to learn and even for that seldom the Kali distro itself is needed. Its only advantage is having it all nicely packaged and (mostly) ready to use but, again, unless you're into pentesting and eventually forensics, Kali isn't for you.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: @ChanganAuto What I'm trying to learn is pentesting as a hobby, I'm experienced with VM's however I just don't want a kali VM on my other computers, and since my empty pc is old it's not very good with VM when it comes to performance. I understand your concern, but I just want to mess around with it. Can you write your comments as an answer so it's more visible for beginer's please?

Comment: You need a solid Linux foundation before jumping into Kali. That includes Linux installation and troubleshooting that is better acquired, again, by using proficiently Debian or derivatives (Debian is the basis for Kali). An no, my comments aren't answers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for your advices. I just want a kali computer.

Comment: Installation instruction were already provided in the first comments.

Comment: @John Following the tutorial worked, turns out my pc put the secure boot option to a different screen. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want either Windows or Ubuntu on this machine, you can replace them with Kali.

Download the Kali installer (bare metal installer) from the Kali website.

Now format your disk to remove Windows and Ubuntu, and then install Kali.

Here is a Kali Tutorial on installing Kali.  I have done this on a Kali Virtual Machine.

https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/